# Konjunktiv I Vergangenheit: Perfekt vs. Präteritum

Tags: subjunctive, past, preterite

Do I understand it correctly that the Past form of the Konjunktiv 1 exists only in Perfekt and there is no such thing as *Konjunktiv 1 Vergangenheit im Präteritum*?

In other words, there is only this form of Konjunktiv I in the Past:

> Konjunktiv I Vergangenheit = Konjunktiv I von sein/haben + Partizip II

Comment: I think that technically, Konjunktiv II is "Konjunktiv Präteritum", just as Konjunktiv I is Konjunktiv Präsens. The German Konjunktive are just so little related to their corresponding tenses that naming them that way is pretty misleading.

Comment: @phipsgabler, I just want to ensure, when in exam I have a sentence in *Präteritum* which must be transformed to *Indirekte Rede*, which is based on *K1*, which form of *K1* should I use: `Konjunktiv I von sein/haben + Partizip II` or something else?

Comment: Oh, yes, exactly that. David has expressed my point much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simple forms

There are four finite forms that can be classified along two categories **tense** and **mood**, the tense features being **present** and **past**, the mood features being **indicative** and **subjunctive**.

Using 3rd person singular, the forms for strong and weak verbs look like this:

```
| (strong)    | present | past   |
|-------------|---------|--------|
| indicative  | trägt   | trug   |
| subjunctive | trage   | trüge  |

|  (weak)     | present | past   |
|-------------|---------|--------|
| indicative  | macht   | machte |
| subjunctive | mache   | machte |
```

**Past** as a **morphological feature** is not the same as **past tense**. Most importantly, the **past subjunctive** *(hätte, wäre, trüge …)* does not refer to the past and the contrast between the two subjunctive forms is not of a temporal nature.

Therefore, a different terminology is often used. The subjunctive forms are usually referred to as **Konjunktiv I** (present subjunctive) and **Konjunktiv II** (past subjunctive). The indicative forms are called **Präsens** (present indicative) and **Präteritum** (past indicative).

It can be seen at this point that the phrase *Konjunktiv 1 Vergangenheit im Präteritum* contains a contradiction: *Konjunktiv 1* and *Präteritum* are incompatible. *Konjunktiv 1* and *Vergangenheit*, however, are not; see below.

## The periphrastic past (perfect)

The **periphrastically** formed **past tense** is called the **perfect**. It is formed with an auxiliary verb *haben* or *sein* and a past participle. Since the auxiliary can take any of the four finite forms listed above, the perfect is actually a family of forms, **depending on the form the auxiliary takes**:

1. present indicative: er hat gearbeitet
2. past indicative: er hatte gearbeitet
3. present subjunctive *(Konjunktiv I)*: er habe gearbeitet
4. past subjunctive *(Konjunktiv II)*: er hätte gearbeitet

The *Institut for Deutsche Sprache* [calls](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/685) these tenses: 1. *Indikativ Präsensperfekt*, 2. *Indikativ Präteritumperfekt*, 3. *Konjunktiv Präsensperfekt* and 4. *Konjunktiv Präteritumperfekt*.

*Konjunktiv Präsensperfekt* combines *Konjunktiv 1* *(habe)* and past tense.

## Contexts where a perfect substitutes for a past indicative

The two past tenses – the past indicative *(Präteritum)* and the periphrastic perfect in all forms – both refer to the past. But the perfect, being a family of tenses, can express distinctions that the simple past cannot. Therefore, in certain cases, a shift from simple past to perfect occurs.

For instance, when a **combination** of **past tense** and **Konjunktiv II** is required, **Konjunktiv Präteritumperfekt** is used:

> Er **arbeitete** nicht viel.
>
> → Er sieht nicht so aus, als **hätte** er viel **gearbeitet**.

When a **combination** of **past tense** and **Konjunktiv I** is required, **Konjunktiv Präsensperfekt** is used:

> Er **arbeitete** nicht viel.
>
> → Ihm wurde vorgeworfen, er **habe** nicht viel **gearbeitet**.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Regarding «present subjunctive, excludes past», I have a sentence: *Nach Auskunft der Werkstatt habe das Auto noch nicht repariert werden können.*, which is obviously past (`habe + repariert werden können`) but still in K1, while *Nach Auskunft der Werkstatt könne das Auto noch nicht repariert werden.* is in Present, isn't?

Comment: @MikeB. The terminology is difficult here because **past** has two meanings: a morphological one (*hatte, war* and *hätte, wäre* are morphologically past) and a temporal one (*hat gearbeitet* and *arbeitete* both refer to the past). *Habe … können* refers to the past, but *habe* and *könne* are present subjunctive (Konjunktiv 1) and do not refer to the past. I don't know how to circumvent this terminological problem.

Comment: "Two categories **tense** and **mood**, the **tense** features..., the **mode** features...". So, it is the **mood** or the **mode** features? Just want to be sure there is no typo here.

Comment: @MikeB. Two words for the same thing. I should stick to one though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really interesting info, regardless if I'll have a K1 question or not on the test!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that *Indikativ Präteritumperfekt* is actually the same as *Indikativ Plusquamperfekt*?

Comment: @MikeB. I'm sure it's been called that. The IDS terminology has the advantage of being self-explanatory: a combination of *haben/sein* with the past participle is called *Perfekt*, with the different types being distinguished by the form of the auxiliary.